# jQuery and setInterval for HotFolder

Tags: jquery, if-statement, setinterval

I would like to create an hotfolder. A Hotfolder is a folder when a file was upload on, an application works. So I would like in my webpage check this folder in ajax.
On click button, jQuery tell a php file (this PHP check folder). When a file is upload on the folder, jQuery tell me. 
I would like to stop the checking when PHP find a file.

My jQuery code :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#strap_signup").click(function(){
            var refreshId = setInterval(function() {
                $("#responsecontainer").load('file_check.php');
            }, 1000); 




        }); 
    });
    </script>
```

My PHP Code :

```
<?php
$ftp_user_name="XXXX";
$ftp_user_pass="XXXX";
$destination_file="/Folder/in";
$conn_id = ftp_connect("XXXX");
$login_result = ftp_login($conn_id, "$ftp_user_name", "$ftp_user_pass");
$contents = ftp_nlist($conn_id, $destination_file);
$om = count($contents);

if($om!="0") echo "File is in";


?>
```

This is work, but when php find the file, jQuery continue to check.
I would like to Stop It.

Something like this :

```
"if($("#responsecontainer")=="File is in"){window.clearInterval(refreshId);}"
```

More, my application take the file in the folder "in", works and put in the folder "out".

So I would like to check "IN", if file is dectected, check "OUT" to control the good job.

Thanks for yours help

Answer (score 0):

Nearly, you dont need window.clearInterval get rid of the window bit and just have:

```
clearInterval(refreshId)
```